# check two bool values and produce single result in mvc2

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2, boolean

I have two types of values,

- Male
- Female

In db these two stores **True or False** and separate fields.

I want to show these values in page, if male is true means will show **"Male"**. If Female is true means will show **Female**. If both means show **Male, Female**.

so, I try,

```
<% if (Model.Male==true) { %>
            <%:"Male" %>
         <% } else if(Model.Female==true){ %>
            <%:"Female" %>
         <% } else { %>
            <%:"Male,Female" %>
         <% } %>
```

But, My result comes

Gender : Male only for all.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By computing the gender inside the view you're ignoring the architecture of the Model-View-Control concept. The idea behinds MVC is to calculate and compute any property of the model inside the model. So the right way to solve you problem is by declaring a new property inside you model called GenderText like so:

```
    public string GenderText
    {
        get { return Male ? (Female ? "Male, Female" : "Male") : "Female"; }
    }
```